# implementing override in my repository

Tags: nixos, nixpkgs

## what i want

https://nixos.org/nixpkgs/manual/#sec-pkg-overrideAttrs documents `overrideAttrs` and it can be used with `top-level/all-packages.nix`.

so i want to be able to use overrideAttrs in my own nixpkgs overlay!

## the code

```
rec {
  frontend = pkgs.callPackage "${nixcloud-frontend}/release.nix" {
    inherit nixcloud-editor;
  };

  AAA = frontend.overrideAttrs  (oldAttrs: rec {
    API_HOST="wss://";
  });

  helloWithDebug = pkgs.hello.overrideAttrs (oldAttrs: rec {
    separateDebugInfo = true;
  });

}
```

## problem

but the problem is evaluating `AAA` won't work:

```
nix-build nixcloud-pkgs.nix -A AAA
error: attribute ‘overrideAttrs’ missing, at /home/joachim/Desktop/projects/nixcloud/nixcloud-webservices/nixcloud-pkgs.nix:17:9
```

in contrast, evaluating `helloWithDebug` works:

```
nix-build nixcloud-pkgs.nix -A helloWithDebug
these derivations will be built:
  /nix/store/x01q7lfqbwlj08iknph37jxh2bk3il68-hello-2.10.drv
these paths will be fetched (0.69 MiB download, 0.69 MiB unpacked):
  /nix/store/3x7dwzq014bblazs7kq20p9hyzz0qh8g-hello-2.10.tar.gz
```

## hint

in nixpkgs i see:

`lib/customisation.nix` used in `lib/default.nix` for which i can't say where it is injected yet.

## hacking nixpkgs

to see the stack i just added breaking code into `lib/customisation.nix`:

```
nix-build -I nixpkgs=../nixpkgs -A tests --show-trace                                                                 ~/Desktop/projects/nixos/nixpkgs
error: while evaluating anonymous function at /home/joachim/Desktop/projects/nixos/nixpkgs/pkgs/top-level/impure.nix:15:1, called from undefined position:
while evaluating anonymous function at /home/joachim/Desktop/projects/nixos/nixpkgs/pkgs/top-level/default.nix:20:1, called from /home/joachim/Desktop/projects/nixos/nixpkgs/pkgs/top-level/impure.nix:64:1:
while evaluating anonymous function at /home/joachim/Desktop/projects/nixos/nixpkgs/pkgs/stdenv/booter.nix:42:1, called from /home/joachim/Desktop/projects/nixos/nixpkgs/pkgs/top-level/default.nix:97:10:
while evaluating ‘dfold’ at /home/joachim/Desktop/projects/nixos/nixpkgs/pkgs/stdenv/booter.nix:60:27, called from /home/joachim/Desktop/projects/nixos/nixpkgs/pkgs/stdenv/booter.nix:104:4:
while evaluating ‘go’ at /home/joachim/Desktop/projects/nixos/nixpkgs/pkgs/stdenv/booter.nix:63:18, called from /home/joachim/Desktop/projects/nixos/nixpkgs/pkgs/stdenv/booter.nix:71:8:
while evaluating the file ‘/home/joachim/Desktop/projects/nixos/nixpkgs/lib/default.nix’:
syntax error, unexpected ID, expecting '.' or '=', at /home/joachim/Desktop/projects/nixos/nixpkgs/lib/customisation.nix:37:3
```

Comment: i should probably be using https://nixos.org/nixpkgs/manual/#sec-overlays-install

Comment: https://mailman.science.uu.nl/pipermail/nix-dev/2016-December/022386.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## what i did in the end

```
cat nixcloud-pkgs.nix
{  pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {}
,  nixcloud-backend   ? pkgs.stdenv.lib.cleanSource ../nixcloud-backend
,  nixcloud-frontend  ? pkgs.stdenv.lib.cleanSource ../nixcloud-frontend
,  nixcloud-editor    ? pkgs.stdenv.lib.cleanSource ../nixcloud-editor
,  nixcloud-container ? pkgs.stdenv.lib.cleanSource ../nixcloud-container
, ...
} @ args:
let
  nc-backend = nixcloud-backend;
  nc-frontend = nixcloud-frontend;

  newpkgs = import pkgs.path { overlays = [ (self: super: {
    nixcloud-backend  = super.callPackage nc-backend { inherit newpkgs; };
    nixcloud-frontend = super.callPackage "${nc-frontend}/release.nix" {
      inherit nixcloud-editor;
    };

  } ) ]; };
in newpkgs
```

## evaluate this with

```
nix-build nixcloud-pkgs.nix -A nixcloud-frontend
```

## using override

```
cat nixcloud-pkgs.nix
{  pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {}
,  nixcloud-backend   ? pkgs.stdenv.lib.cleanSource ../nixcloud-backend
,  nixcloud-frontend  ? pkgs.stdenv.lib.cleanSource ../nixcloud-frontend
,  nixcloud-editor    ? pkgs.stdenv.lib.cleanSource ../nixcloud-editor
,  nixcloud-container ? pkgs.stdenv.lib.cleanSource ../nixcloud-container
, ...
} @ args:
let
  nc-backend = nixcloud-backend;
  nc-frontend = nixcloud-frontend;

  newpkgs = import pkgs.path { overlays = [ (self: super: {
    nixcloud-backend  = super.callPackage nc-backend { inherit newpkgs; };
    nixcloud-frontend = supber.callPackage "${nc-frontend}/release.nix" {
      inherit nixcloud-editor;
    };

  } ) ]; };
in newpkgs.nixcloud-frontend.override (oldAttrs: rec {
  API_HOST="wss://....";
})
```

## evaluate this with

```
nix-build nixcloud-pkgs.nix
```

## documentation

please see also https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/pull/26321 where this is discussed